# Why is every vertex in $q$ sets?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, linear-programming, coloring

I am reading the paper "[Choosability and fractional chromatic numbers](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=042949aa65527e453db537e5c82b61a3de8537f8)".

It concerns the fractional chromatic numbers of a graph $G$: let $\mathcal{S}(G)$ be the collection of independent sets in $G$. A fractional coloring is a function $f:\mathcal{S}(G)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ such that $\sum_{S\in\mathcal{S}(G):v\in S}f(S)\ge 1$ for every $v\in V(G)$. The fractional chromatic number $\chi^*(G)$ is $\min \sum_{S\in \mathcal{S}(G)}f(S)$ over all fractional coloring $f$.

It is proved that an optimal solution has the form $f(S)=p_S/q$ for $S$ in a subcollection $\mathcal{S}_0(G)$ of $\mathcal{S}$, where $p_S,q$ are positive integers, and the weight on all other $S$ is 0.

At the end of Section 2, it is claimed that "by taking $p_S$ multiplicity of each $S\in\mathcal{S}_0$, then each vertex is in exactly $q$ sets". I am wondering why this is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not *precisely* true that every vertex lies in exactly $q$ sets; however, we can reduce to that case without loss of generality.

First, what do we know? If we take each $S \in \mathcal S_0$ with multiplicity $p_S$, then for every vertex $v$, we have $$\sum_{S \ni v} f(S) \ge 1 \iff \sum_{S \ni v} \frac{p_S}{q} \ge 1 \iff \sum_{S \ni v} p_S \ge q.$$ The last inequality says that the total number of sets $S \in \mathcal S_0$ containing $v$, counted with the multiplicity with which they are taken, is *at least* $q$.

It is not necessarily true that the total number of sets containing each vertex is exactly $q$, counted with multiplicity. To see this, consider the graph below:

```
1 --- 2    3
```

This graph has fractional chromatic number $2$ (or $\frac21$); one way to achieve this is to take $\{1,3\}$ with multiplicity $1$ and $\{2,3\}$ with multiplicity $1$. Then, vertex $3$ is included in more independent sets than expected. However, in this case, there is a different solution: take the sets $\{1,3\}$ and $\{2\}$ instead.

That's always going to happen. If we've turned our fractional solution into a multifamily of independent sets that covers every vertex *at least* $q$ times, then we can always get a multifamily of independent sets that covers every vertex *exactly* $q$ times.

We can get there by local improvements: if there is a vertex $v$ that's covered $q+1$ or more times, take an arbitrary set $S$ containing it, and replace *one* copy of $S$ by a copy of $S \setminus \{v\}$. Repeat as necessary. At each step, we reduce the quantity $\sum_{S \in \mathcal S_0} p_S|S|$ (which tracks the total size of the sets used), so eventually we must stop and reach a point where every vertex is covered exactly $q$ times.